# Ещё одно интересное предложение

Tags: синтаксис

Начал читать комикс «Маус» (Арт Шпигельман). В книге была следующая цитата Адольфа Гитлера:

> Евреи, безусловно, раса, но не человеческая.

Как разобрать это предложение? Вторая часть неполная, где опущено подлежащее *раса*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь возможны два варианта:

1) **Евреи**, безусловно, **раса**, но не **человеческая (раса)**. Простое неполное предложение с однородными сказуемыми.

2) **Евреи**, безусловно, **раса**, но (**раса) не человеческая** . ССП, второе предложение неполное.

Comment: Я тоже так рассуждал.